# Sidekiq retrying old job without termination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

We I renamed a job from JobA to JobB. There were a few jobs in the queue when the change was deployed. Now the old Job keeps getting retried and keeps failing. This job below was actually enqueued 3 weeks ago and Sidekiq is still retrying it.

```
{
  "context": "Job raised exception",
  "job": {
    "args": [
      5105
    ],
    "class": "JobA",
    "created_at": 1499822416.4738095,
    "enqueued_at": 1499822417.145876,
    "jid": "b32957f3e0ad6b89b1331e46",
    "queue": "default",
    "retry": true
  },
  "jobstr": "{\"class\":\"JobA\",\"args\":[5105],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"b32957f3e0ad6b89b1331e46\",\"created_at\":1499822416.4738095,\"enqueued_at\":1499822417.145876}"
}
```

How can I clear the retry queue for a class of jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what works for me for most sidekiq versions:

```
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear

Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
```

Clear statistics

```
Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset
```

To clear specific jobs

```
rogue = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.select { |job| /JobA/.match(job.value) }
rogue.each { |job| job.delete }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've found my rogue jobs in the RetrySet. However I'd like to not nuke the whole set. Is there a way for me to clear a subset. Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.select { |job| /JobA/.match(job.value) }

Comment: Edited your answer to improve the solution

Comment: Thanks @SanjitSaluja I like what you did :)